# View footer area to capture main view search terms

Tags: views

I have a page with a main view which is a Google map display which shows node locations. I can filter these through exposed filters but I can't get these filters to also apply to another view which I placed in the main view footer area.

I thought about using contextual filters in that embedded view, but none seem to do the job when the URL follows the following pattern : /pagename?key1=value1&key2=value2 and so on....

Any idea how I could pick up the search terms from the main view within that embedded view ?

Comment: Any reason you're using a separate view in a footer instead of a views attachment?

Comment: Well, thanks Beth. The only reason why I was using that separate view was my own ignorance of Views Attachment... That will teach me!

Comment: Glad to help. You can also post an answer to your own question here, with details about how you implemented it. It helps future askers find info.

Comment: Ok, so that's how I did it. It is actually very simple, thanks to the aforementioned Views Attachment, which can be added as a Display (like Page and Block). In my specific case, I needed a map with node locations, as well as a list of the same nodes below it, filtered through the same exposed filters. I used a Gmap to generate the main display and an attachment to append another view to it. You can choose its position and inherit exposed filters, which is very useful. I hope this short explanation will help other people!